# Derivation of the Primal Dual Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

I was reading the chapter found [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egoemans/PAPERS/book-ch4.pdf) and am unable to reproduce their derivation of the dual of the restricted primal on page 148. Specifically, they define $J = \{j|A^j y = c_j\}$ and $I = \{i | y_i = 0\}$ based on complementary slackness conditions for the standard form of the primal and dual and then go from the restricted primal:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{min} \quad & \sum_{i \notin I} s_i + \sum_{j \notin J} x_j \\
\text{s.t.}\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
A_i x_i \geq b_i  &\quad i \in I\\
A_i x_i - s_i = b_i &\quad i \notin I \\
x \geq 0 \\
s \geq 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}

to the dual of the restricted primal:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{max} \quad & b^T y' \\
\text{s.t.}\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
A^j y' \leq 0  &\quad j \in J\\
A^j y' \leq 1 &\quad j \notin J \\
y'_i \geq -1 &\quad i \notin I\\
y'_i \geq 0 &\quad i \in I \\
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}

I understand that the first two constraints in the dual of the restricted primal come from the objective term of the restricted primal, where the coefficient of $x_j$ varies based on whether $j \in J$. But, how did they arrive at $y'_i  \geq -1$ for $i \notin I$?